# How to deal with hover animations on touch screens: click on mobile vs hover on pc

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover, touch

I have the following html and CSS to have a box with an image where the title is centered. When hovering, the title is animated up and faded out while the text is faded in and animated from the bottom to the center.

This works well on PC but on touch devices, I have the problem that the user has to touch the image while scrolling to view the text. Touching the image once will immediately open the link.

Is there a way I can make it so that on mobile devices, the animation is executed when the user touches the image for the first time and the link is opened when touching for the second time? Touching outside the image should revert the animation.

I hope you can explain how I could achieve that (if it is possible). Or is there another, generally accepted way to deal with hover on mobile devices?

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text_container {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text_container div {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.image_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.content:hover .image {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

.text_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text_container>div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.text_container .title h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.content:hover .text_container .title h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
}

.text_container .content div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
}

.content:hover .text_container .content div {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="image_container">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2017/fischinger/bg_cta.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="text_container">
            <div class="title">
              <h2>My Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <div>
                Some text.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you think that would be counter intuitive to a users expectations? I think removing the hover effect would be best.

Comment: So you mean on mobile devices, I should show title and text at the same time with no hover effects? Is there a way to do this with css or would it require me to do it in html or js?